# Why forEach var doesn't work as a parameter? JSP/JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, java-ee-6, jsp-tags

```
<c:forEach var = "i" begin = "0" end = "${List.size()}">
  <option value="2" selected>
    ${List.get(i).getName()}
  </option>
</c:forEach>
```

My arraylist (List) works and also the forEach, but I don't understand why the var **i** is not able to reach as a **parameter** for the function **get()**. But if I use it like **${i}** it works, also if I want to print **${List.get(0).getName()}** sending a number as a paramether it works.

So my question is why **"i"** doesn't work when is used as a parameter to get the list that I want.

I also tried these:

```
<c:out value="${List.get(i).getName()}"/>

<%=List.get(i).getName()%>
```

Comment: have you tried `List[i].name`?

Comment: @f1sh I don't understand how but it worked because I'm using an arraylist, so I'm suppose to use get() to get the arraylist that I want. If you want you can submit the answer and thanks <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is the syntax. You expect to write java code in these places, however JSP expects these expression to follow the syntax of the [Expression Language](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html) ("EL").

In EL, array/List/Map elements are accessed [using brackets](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnahu.html). Properties are expected to follow the naming convention of getters, so `.name` will internally be translated to `getName()`.

Overall, your expression should be

```
List[i].name
```

which EL evaluates one by one, eventually returning the same as `List.get(i).getName()`.